# How to get LayoutResult for ColumnDocumentRenderer with Rectangle Array

Tags: itext7

The code below renders a Paragraph into 4 Rectangle areas by using a ColumnDocumentRenderer. Before the cdr.draw() method is called I would like to determine if the text was too long to fit. If it is, I would use setHorizontalScaling to make it fit.

I'd like to accomplish this using the ColumnDocumentRenderer.layout method which produces a LayoutResult.  But, it takes a single Rectangle bBox: cdr.layout(new LayoutContext(new LayoutArea(pageNumber, bBox)));

Is there a way to iterate through the areas and find out if all of the areas were filled and the last will overflow?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(DEST));
    PdfPage page = pdfDoc.addNewPage();
    PdfCanvas pdfCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(50, 560, 200, 20);
    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(50, 540, 200, 20);
    Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle(25, 520, 275, 20);
    Rectangle r4 = new Rectangle(25, 500, 275, 20);
    Rectangle[] rects = { r1, r2, r3, r4 };

    Text t = new Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt "
            + "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris "
            + "nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. "); 
    t.setFontSize(10f);
    //t.setHorizontalScaling(.85f);

    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(); 
    p.setMargin(0);
    p.setMultipliedLeading(1);
    p.add(t);
    p.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED);

    ParagraphRenderer pr = (ParagraphRenderer)p.createRendererSubTree();

    ColumnDocumentRenderer cdr = new ColumnDocumentRenderer(doc, rects);
    cdr.addChild(pr);


    cdr.draw(new DrawContext(pdfDoc, pdfCanvas));
    pdfDoc.close();
}
```

Comment: A call to the layout method of a renderer returns a layout-result that among other information contains whether overflow occured. If you're doing this kind of dynamic layouting, be sure to have immediateFlush turned off at the document level (it's on by default)

Comment: But, I am thinking that I can't call the layout method in this case because it takes a single rectangle as a parameter to the LayoutContent(LayoutArea()) constructors.   Here, I need it to take the array of Rectangles.  Or, perhaps iterate through the children renderers getting the LayoutResult of each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important point here is that root renderers do not support `layout` operation. However, they have `getCurrentArea()` method that allows you to track the current unused position in the document.

The idea is to layout the paragraph and see if we found ourselves on the second page or the first one and if overflow occurred (second page), then shrink the text.

Depending on your use case, this method might need some alterations, especially in the part of removing the pages, but I assume that you create the document from scratch, as you do in the sample provided in the question.

The approach looks like this in the code:

```
float step = 0.05f;
float curHorScaling = 1;
ColumnDocumentRenderer cdr;
while (true) {
    // Remove extra pages and create a new, clean ColumnDocumentRenderer
    while (doc.getPdfDocument().getNumberOfPages() > 1) {
        doc.getPdfDocument().removePage(1);
    }
    cdr = new ColumnDocumentRenderer(doc, false, rects);
    t.setHorizontalScaling(curHorScaling);
    cdr.getChildRenderers().clear();
    cdr.addChild(p.createRendererSubTree());
    If one page is not enough, decrease the scaling, otherwise go to drawing
    if (cdr.getCurrentArea().getPageNumber() > 1) {
        curHorScaling -= step;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Full modified code:

```
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(50, 560, 200, 20);
Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(50, 540, 200, 20);
Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle(25, 520, 275, 20);
Rectangle r4 = new Rectangle(25, 500, 275, 20);
Rectangle[] rects = { r1, r2, r3, r4 };

Text t = new Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt "
        + "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris "
        + "nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. ");
t.setFontSize(10f);

Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.setMargin(0);
p.setMultipliedLeading(1);
p.add(t);
p.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED);

float step = 0.05f;
float curHorScaling = 1;
ColumnDocumentRenderer cdr;
while (true) {
    while (doc.getPdfDocument().getNumberOfPages() > 0) {
        doc.getPdfDocument().removePage(1);
    }
    cdr = new ColumnDocumentRenderer(doc, false, rects);
    t.setHorizontalScaling(curHorScaling);
    cdr.getChildRenderers().clear();
    cdr.addChild(p.createRendererSubTree());
    if (cdr.getCurrentArea().getPageNumber() > 1) {
        curHorScaling -= step;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

cdr.draw(new DrawContext(pdfDoc, new PdfCanvas(pdfDoc.getFirstPage())));
pdfDoc.close();
```